# How to start on-chain permissioning with ibft consensus

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-besu

I am try to start besu blockchain with ibft consensus protocol.
For enabling on-chain permissioning, I followed the steps descrived in totorial.
But I couldn't deploy permissing-related contracts.
ibft requires at least 4 validators for transaction mint.
But the tutorial guides contract migration when only Node-1 is started.
With only a single node, I guess the trasaction never complete.

Could you kindly provide guide to start ibft blockchain with on-chain permissiong?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ConsenSys/permissioning-smart-contracts

I failed to deploy permissioned smart contracts on besu network.
When i tried with ganache. I was able setup the ui. Add node is disabled though.

Mining can happen with single node as well with bootnode. It needs 4 to become Byzantine fault tolerant